# webpack + swagger + gulp : bundle controllers?

Tags: node.js, gulp, webpack, swagger

I'm new using Webpack and Swagger with NodeJS.  I am using webpack + gulp on the backend side, I think it's mostly because I want to deploy something "bundled" and "packaged".
I saw that bundling the main server script `app.js` works fine.

I saw Swagger needs a particular project tree :

- `api/controllers` : for controller files
- `api/swagger` : for the config file

**This is what I tried :**

Bundling file `api/controllers/Controllers.js`

```
var _ = require('lodash');

_.merge(exports, require('Ctrl1'));
_.merge(exports, require('Ctrl2'));
_.merge(exports, require('Ctrl3'));
```

Also tried with

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var Controllers = {};
_.merge(Controllers, require('Ctrl1'));
_.merge(Controllers, require('Ctrl2'));
_.merge(Controllers, require('Ctrl3'));

module.exports = Controllers;
```

The bundled file `controllers.js` looks fine.

And in `swagger.yaml` :

```
x-swagger-router-controller: controllers
```

**I get this error if I try the requests :**

```
Controller controllers doesn't export handler function functionName
```

**A console.log(controllersModule) prints :**

```
{ functionName: [Function: functionName], ... }
```

Can you help ? Is this even possible to achieve ?

Thanks for your help :).